# Localizable.strings - translation split over multiple lines

Tags: ios, localization

Should be simple...

I have a translation file (Localizable.strings) in ios (actually RubyMotion project) and I want to split the translation over multiple lines WITHOUT the newline characters. Eg:

```
"string_to_translate" = "this is the translation "+
                        "that I want over multiple lines";
"next_translation" = "next translation";
```

Can't get it to work, does anyone know the correct syntax? Thanks.

Comment: Simple: You cannot do this. Strings in Localizable.strings must be on a single line. I know it's annoying, but that's what it is.

Comment: Wow, that is annoying, thanks @gnasher729